# Autobidder is skipping seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building penny auction website. I have some problem with autobidder. At first I made bash script (was opening php) and set sleep 1 second, but server skipped some seconds, Than I tried to run event from phpmyadmin but the same thing. times in  log table when it skipped was like this:

```
23:08:02; 
23:08:06; 
23:08:16; 
23:08:16; 
23:08:16; 
23:08:18; 
23:08:19; 
23:08:20; 
23:08:21;
```

How can I make Autobidder not to skip seconds?

Here is code which I was using in phpmyadmin events:

```
BEGIN
SET @user_id = 0;
SET @product_id = 0;
SET @CurPrice = 0;
SET @plusSec = 12;
SET @intervalSec = 3;

SELECT @user_id:=au.user_id,@price := au.price,@CurPrice := pr.CurrentPrice + CONCAT('0.0',pr.x), @x :=pr.x,
                 @product_id := au.product_id
FROM autobids AS au
LEFT JOIN products AS pr ON au.product_id = pr.id 
WHERE(au.user_id !=
(SELECT user_id
    FROM bids_log
    WHERE products_id = pr.id
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) AND( pr.endDate > NOW()
    AND pr.endDate <= NOW() + interval @intervalSec second)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO `table_name`.`bids_log` (`id`, `products_id`, `user_id`, `price`,`data`)
VALUES (NULL, @product_id, @user_id, @CurPrice, NOW());

UPDATE `table_name`.`products` SET `CurrentPrice` = @CurPrice ,`endDate` =  DATE_ADD(endDate, INTERVAL @plusSec second) WHERE `products`.`id` = @product_id;

UPDATE `table_name`.`autobids` SET `price` = `price` - @x  WHERE `user_id` = @user_id AND `product_id`= @product_id;
INSERT INTO `table_name`.`event` (`id`, `rame`) VALUES (NULL, NOW());
END
```

Comment: Please add sample code.

Comment: I've added Event code.